# The title of an RSS feed should display the tag first

Tags: discussion, feed

A long time ago, the title of a RSS feed for tag 'foobar' was "foobar Questions". Now, it is "active questions tagged foobar". In a RSS reader with limited space (I use Sage), I see by default only the first two words, which do not discriminate enough.

I think we should go back to the old name, with the tag first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not rename feeds in Sage? I know in Google Reader you can rename a feed to something that makes sense to you:

[Rename http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/9882/renamefeed.png](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/9882/renamefeed.png)

Comment: Yes, but I have many feeds so it will take time.

Comment: Accepted, since there was nothing else suggested but inconvenient since I have many feeds to rename.